# Trying to dockerize Sails 1.0.2 with PostgreSQL, can't connect to DB by any means

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, sails.js

I've been trying to dockerize a Sails 1.0.2 app to be able to run it locally with docker-compose, but it doesn't seem to be able to connect to PostgreSQL server by any means.

Also, I think I might be missing some concepts on how DB creation works with Sails. I've tried either model "safe" behaviour (for manual migrations), "alter" and "drop".

When running safe mode, I tried using `sails-migrations db:create`, or `sails-migrations migrate` in a separate task within the container to check if any of them would be necessary for setting up the database, even though I still have **only a scaffold generated User.js model**.

None of them seem to work. On the other way, the Docker database itself looks like it was created. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Versions I'm using:

**Sails**: 1.0.2

**PostgreSQL**: 9.6

**sails-migrations**: 2.1.0

**sails-postgresql**: 1.0.0

---

### File List:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  postgres_data_dev: {}
  postgres_backup_dev: {}

services:
  postgres:
  build: ./compose/postgres
  volumes:
    - postgres_data_dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    - postgres_backup_dev:/backups
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=test_project
  sails:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/sails/Dockerfile
    command: /start-dev.sh
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=test_project
      - USE_DOCKER=yes
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - postgres
```

---

**compose/sails/Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest

RUN npm install -g sails grunt npm-check-updates

COPY ./package.json /package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install --save sails-postgresql

COPY ./compose/sails/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

COPY ./compose/sails/start-dev.sh /start-dev.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start-dev.sh
RUN chmod +x /start-dev.sh

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

---

**compose/sails/entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
cmd="$@"

export REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379

# the official postgres image uses 'postgres' as default user if not set explictly.
if [ -z "$POSTGRES_USER" ]; then
  export POSTGRES_USER=postgres
fi

export     DATABASE_URL=postgres://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@postgres:5432/$POSTGRES_USER


function postgres_ready(){
  node << END
var postgres = require("pg");
var client = new postgres.Client({
  user: '$POSTGRES_USER',
  password: '$POSTGRES_PASSWORD',
  database: '$POSTGRES_USER',
  port: 5432,
  host: 'postgres',
});
client.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('connection failed');
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
  console.log('connection successful');
  process.exit(0);
});
END
}

until postgres_ready; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - continuing..."
exec $cmd
```

---

**compose/sails/start-dev.sh**
`sails lift --port 8000 --verbose`

---

**compose/postgres/Dockerfile**

```
FROM postgres:9.6

# add backup scripts
ADD backup.sh /usr/local/bin/backup
ADD restore.sh /usr/local/bin/restore
ADD list-backups.sh /usr/local/bin/list-backups

# make them executable
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/restore
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/list-backups
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/backup
```

---

**config/datastores.js**

```
  default: {
    adapter: "sails-postgresql",
    user: "test_project",
    host: "localhost",
  },
```

---

### Notes and error outputs

**Note:** I've also tried datastores url: 'postgresql://test_project@localhost:5432' and 'postgresql://test_project@localhost:5432/postgres' instead of separate declarations for each attribute on the connection string.

Although the database created by Docker seems to be fine, I keep getting either **ECONNREFUSED** (probably whenever I play around with docker DB or DB connection's parameters to try and make it work), or the following error (when it connects to the DB successfully):

```
error: Could not tear down the ORM hook. 
Error details: Error: Invalid data store identity. 
No data store exist with that identity.
```

### The error's full output can be found down below (when using model **alter** strategy):

```
sails_1     | Postgres is unavailable - sleeping
postgres_1  |  done
postgres_1  | server stopped
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-09-05 13:45:04 UTC
postgres_1  | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
postgres_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
sails_1     | connection successful
sails_1     | Postgres is up - continuing...
sails_1     |
sails_1     |  info: Starting app...
sails_1     |
sails_1     | verbo: Using locally-installed Sails.
sails_1     | verbo: • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • •
sails_1     | verbo: •  Loading Sails with "verbose" logging enabled...        •
sails_1     | verbo: •  (For even more details, try "silly".)                  •
sails_1     | verbo: •                                                         •
sails_1     | verbo: •  http://sailsjs.com/config/log                          •
sails_1     | verbo: • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • • •
sails_1     | verbo: moduleloader hook loaded successfully. (0ms)
sails_1     | verbo: userconfig hook loaded successfully. (104ms)
sails_1     | verbo: Exposing global variables... (you can customize/disable this by modifying the properties in `sails.config.globals`.  Set it to `false` to disable all globals.)
sails_1     | verbo: userhooks hook loaded successfully. (8669ms)
sails_1     | verbo: logger hook loaded successfully. (4ms)
sails_1     | verbo: request hook loaded successfully. (0ms)
sails_1     | verbo: views hook loaded successfully. (46ms)
sails_1     | verbo: responses hook loaded successfully. (49ms)
sails_1     | verbo: helpers hook loaded successfully. (11ms)
sails_1     | verbo: policies hook loaded successfully. (9ms)
sails_1     | verbo: services hook loaded successfully. (1ms)
sails_1     | verbo: security hook loaded successfully. (4ms)
sails_1     | verbo: i18n hook loaded successfully. (19ms)
sails_1     | verbo: session hook loaded successfully. (149ms)
sails_1     | verbo: http hook loaded successfully. (1341ms)
sails_1     |  info: Initializing hook... (`api/hooks/custom`)
sails_1     | verbo: Some optional settings have not been configured yet:
sails_1     | ---------------------------------------------------------------------
sails_1     | No `sails.config.custom.stripeSecret` was configured.
sails_1     | No `sails.config.custom.stripePublishableKey` was configured.
sails_1     | No `sails.config.custom.mailgunSecret` was configured.
sails_1     | No `sails.config.custom.mailgunDomain` was configured.
sails_1     |
sails_1     | Until this is addressed, this app's billing and email features
sails_1     | will be disabled and/or hidden in the UI.
sails_1     |
sails_1     |  [?] If you're unsure or need advice, come by https://sailsjs.com/support
sails_1     | ---------------------------------------------------------------------
sails_1     | verbo: custom hook loaded successfully. (1ms)
sails_1     |  info: Initializing `apianalytics` hook...  (requests to monitored routes will be logged!)
sails_1     | verbo: apianalytics hook loaded successfully. (0ms)
sails_1     | verbo: grunt hook loaded successfully. (11ms)
sails_1     | verbo: organics hook loaded successfully. (135ms)
sails_1     | verbo: sockets hook loaded successfully. (205ms)
sails_1     | verbo: Loading adapter (`sails-postgresql`) from this app's `node_modules/` directory...
sails_1     |  info: ·• Auto-migrating...  (alter)
sails_1     |  info:    Hold tight, this could take a moment.
sails_1     | error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
sails_1     | verbo: Lowering sails...
sails_1     | error: Could not tear down the ORM hook.  Error details: Error: Invalid data store identity. No data store exist with that identity.
sails_1     |     at Object.teardown (/app/node_modules/sails-postgresql/helpers/teardown.js:60:26)
sails_1     |     at wrapper (/app/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3275:19)
sails_1     |     at Deferred.parley.retry [as _handleExec] (/app/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1076:19)
sails_1     |     at Deferred.exec (/app/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:286:10)
sails_1     |     at Deferred.switch (/app/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1469:16)
sails_1     |     at teardownDatastore (/app/node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js:96:18)
sails_1     |     at /app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3047:20
sails_1     |     at replenish (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:884:21)
sails_1     |     at /app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:888:13
sails_1     |     at eachLimit$1 (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3136:26)
sails_1     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:920:20)
sails_1     |     at Object.teardown (/app/node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js:91:13)
sails_1     |     at /app/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline.js:758:27
sails_1     |     at /app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3047:20
sails_1     |     at eachOfArrayLike (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1002:13)
sails_1     |     at eachOf (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1052:9)
sails_1     |     at Object.eachLimit (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3111:7)
sails_1     |     at Object.teardown (/app/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline.js:742:11)
sails_1     |     at Hook.teardown (/app/node_modules/sails-hook-orm/index.js:246:30)
sails_1     |     at Sails.wrapper (/app/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3275:19)
sails_1     |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
sails_1     |     at Sails.emit (events.js:182:13)
sails_1     |     at Sails.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
sails_1     |     at Sails.emitter.emit (/app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/after.js:56:26)
sails_1     |     at /app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/lower.js:67:11
sails_1     |     at beforeShutdown (/app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/lower.js:45:12)
sails_1     |     at Sails.lower (/app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/lower.js:49:3)
sails_1     |     at Sails.wrapper [as lower] (/app/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3275:19)
sails_1     | verbo: (The error above was logged like this because `sails.hooks.orm.teardown()` encountered an error in a code path where it was invoked without providing a callback.)
sails_1     | error:
sails_1     | error: Exception: `registerDataStore` failed ("badConfiguration").  The configuration was invalid.  (Also got an additional error -- see `.raw`).
sails_1     |     at Object.registerDatastore (/app/node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js:56:17)
sails_1     |     at /app/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline.js:714:27
sails_1     |     at /app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3047:20
sails_1     |     at eachOfArrayLike (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1002:13)
sails_1     |     at eachOf (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1052:9)
sails_1     |     at Object.eachLimit (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3111:7)
sails_1     |     at Object.initialize (/app/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline.js:650:11)
sails_1     |     at buildOntologyAndRunAutoMigrations (/app/node_modules/sails-hook-orm/lib/build-ontology-and-run-auto-migrations.js:55:7)
sails_1     |     at async.auto._buildOntology (/app/node_modules/sails-hook-orm/lib/initialize.js:456:7)
sails_1     |     at runTask (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1660:17)
sails_1     |     at /app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1602:17
sails_1     |     at processQueue (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1612:17)
sails_1     |     at taskComplete (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1630:13)
sails_1     |     at /app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1653:21
sails_1     |     at /app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:339:31
sails_1     |     at /app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:847:20
sails_1     |     at async.auto._checkAdapterCompatibility (/app/node_modules/sails-hook-orm/lib/initialize.js:428:14)
sails_1     |     at runTask (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1660:17)
sails_1     |     at /app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1602:17
sails_1     |     at processQueue (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1612:17)
sails_1     |     at taskComplete (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1630:13)
sails_1     |     at /app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1653:21
sails_1     |
sails_1     | error: Could not load Sails app.
sails_1     | error:
sails_1     | error: Tips:
sails_1     | error:  • First, take a look at the error message above.
sails_1     | error:  • Make sure you've installed dependencies with `npm install`.
sails_1     | error:  • Check that this app was built for a compatible version of Sails.
sails_1     | error:  • Have a question or need help?  (http://sailsjs.com/support)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `datastores.js` references the database host as `localhost`, it should be the name of the docker service `postgres` when running from the compose file. The migration part in `compose/sails/entrypoint.sh` references the host as `postgres`

Comment: You are an angel! I was so biased while reading my code over and over that I didn't notice that. Thank you!